# python script not running due to Errno2 No such file or directory exist

Tags: python, python-3.9

Hi I get this when running python script(prepoc.py). Could it be an issue with the environment variables? [image]

Any idea how to fix this? Thanks
Edit: it's in the directory
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please open the path program and see your program is there. This error means your program is not there.

Comment: it's in the directory though(updated the question)

Comment: Try with IDLE or Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if the prepoc.py is in your folder directory. If it already is, you have to check your **current** working directory by

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

if prepoc.py isn't in the current working directory, place it there.

Comment: it's in the directory though(updated question)

Comment: Well, the file is but the python might be not, as you can see your python.exe isn't in the same directory as the file. You have to check if python is in your environment variables by typing ```py``` or ```python``` into the cmd.